# Saving a file to server using PHP and JS?

Tags: javascript, php, file, server, save

I have been trying this for a few hours now, googling around and trying several approaches. The code is so simple I don't understand why it doesn't work. I am using 000webhost free hosting atm just to test this out.

I literally just wanna pass a variable to the php file for it to save in a text file, in this case "ayy".
Latest code (file does not even get created):

JS Code

```
function doSave(){
xhr.open("POST", "save.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send("ayy");
}
```

PHP code (save.php)

```
<?php
file_put_contents('data.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

I did also have this code below earlier, however it only created a blank file and would not append any text to it:

index.htm

```
function doSave(){
    var datastr = "ayy";
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "save.php", true);
  xmlhttp.send(datastr);
}
```

save.php

```
<?php
$post_data = $_POST['datastr'];
$f = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
fwrite($f, $post_data);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Any suggestions why this might not be working? All I can think of is the server not supporting it or something, however I can get it working fine if I specify the variable IN the php file and using a GET request to simply just post the variable. However the data is going to be dynamic so I need to pass it from client-side using js.

Thanks.

Comment: In your second example, you should have `file_get_contents('php://input');` instead of `$_POST['datastr']`. If you rather want it in your `$_POST`, you would need to pass it in the send method as: `datastr=ayy` instead of just the value.

Comment: Btw, in your first example, you never define `xhr` in your js function before you start using it. Is it defined outside?

Comment: Oh my god I have no idea how I missed declaring xhr. The code works now (first example). Thanks!!